# Binding DataTable to DataGrid. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, datatable, binding, datagrid

I am trying to bind a Datatable on a Datagrid to be able to fill it dynamically.
The Datagrid seems to find the Datatable because when I fill it and after the RaisePropertyChanged I have a lot of blank rows. There are no columns too.

**My View:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="NWViewer.View.DataGridView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NWViewer.View"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding DataGrid, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding oTable.DefaultView}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ColumnWidth="25">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public DataTable oTable { get;set;}

private void getNewData(List<ElementBaseViewModel> rootElement)
{    
    oTable.Clear();
    foreach (var element in rootElement)
    {
        buildFromChildren(element);                      
    }
    RaisePropertyChanged("oTable");                
}        
private void buildFromChildren(ElementBaseViewModel element)
    {
        if(element.Children != null)
        {
            if (isAttributeChildren(element))
            {
                DataRow oRow = oTable.NewRow();
                foreach (var attribute in element.AttributeChildren)
                {
                    Model.Attribute attr = (Model.Attribute)attribute.Element;
                    if (!oTable.Columns.Contains(attr.name))
                    oTable.Columns.Add(attr.name);
                    oRow[attr.name] = attr.Value;
                }
                oTable.Rows.Add(oRow);
            }
            foreach (var elem in element.ElementChildren)
            {
                buildFromChildren(elem);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is the graphical rendering :

[Datagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fq00N.png)

But the DataTable seems correctly filled when i debug it :

[DataTable when debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VvBo.png)

Comment: Please add more information ([see MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). It's hard to help unless we know what happens eg. in `buildFromChildren`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most probably related to the `DataTable` initialization, `DataGrid` will auto-generate columns when a new `ItemsSource` is set, but it will not re-generate columns when columns are added to the underlying table after initialization.

Solution 1:

Create all columns on initialization of the `DataTable`, before binding it to the `DataGrid`.

Solution 2:

Force refresh the `ItemsSource`. It should work like this, but I highly recommend Solution 1 if possible:

```
var tempTable = oTable;
oTable = null;
RaisePropertyChanged("oTable");
oTable = tempTable;
RaisePropertyChanged("oTable");
```

Comment: THX BRO. This is the solution. I have not thought at this. You saved my day!

Comment: @Ant4r no problem. If this solved your question, you should accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work